# How do I increase GPU quota limit on google cloud

Tags: google-cloud-platform, cloud, gpu, quota

I have been having a problem increasing my GPU quota on Google Cloud. It put my current limit for GPU to 0.
[image]

Anytime I try to increase the quota by editing the quota on the quotas pages, it tells me to contact sales. When I contacted sales, they said they only deal with company requests and they told me to contact technical support. Unfortunately, community support doesn't seem to have an answer/solution. They suggest you pay for the standard support plan($29). I decided to try to get the standard support. But once again, it requires me to have an organisation resource.
[image]
To get the organisation resources I need to have a company domain.
[image]
It just seems that google cloud is made for only companies and not individuals. Does anyone know how to go around this?

Answer (score 1):

- If your project is under a free trial program, you can't add GPUs to your VM instances or can't request a quota increase. It is a limitation under the free trial you can find under the 'Program coverage' section of the free trial documentation.
- After enabling a billing account Please navigate to the Cloud Console and select the resources you want to modify. Then click Edit Quotas at the top of the page to start the Quota Increase process.
- Check the Quotas page to ensure that you have enough GPUs available in your project, and to request a quota increase. In addition, new accounts and projects have a global GPU quota that applies to all regions.
- If the resources you are trying to increase aren't displayed in the page and the current filtering is "Quotas with usage" then, please, change the filtering to "All quotas" by toggling the "Quota type" Dropdown in the top left of the page.
- **Refer to this official [doc](https://cloud.google.com/compute/resource-usage#gpus) on how to increase GPU quota limit and check this official [doc](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/gpus/gpu-regions-zones)  for GPU regions and zones availability**

  If  you are still  facing an error try below steps for increasing the GPU quota:
- In the filter at the top of the quotas page, type  Service: Compute Engine API and Limit Name: GPUs (all regions) and changed the limit from 0 to 1 or more